# How to pass Parameters to json?

Tags: android, web-services

I want to pass the below info to Json service.

> username=m@m.com&password=mmmmm&apikey=12345&class=User

I get the data from json.But how to pass the above parameters to json service.

I fallow the below code.
but it returns some java script.

```
public void Sample1()
{
    try {
        String response;
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                 "url");
                 post.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json" );
                 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new
                 ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "m@m.com"));
                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "mmmmm"));
                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("apikey", "12345"));
                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("class", "User"));

                 post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 HttpResponse resp = client.execute(post);
                 HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();

                 response = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                 Log.v("info",">>>>"+response);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

If any one know the solution.

Please help me.

Comment: What is it sending as the error?

Comment: I didn't get any error.just it returns some java script

Comment: You should print response.toString() in ur logcat

Comment: You want to pass JSON into request or want to parse response JSON?

Comment: i want to send some parames and read responce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is class called **JSONArray ** and **JSONObject**. To get this class in you project you need to import

> import org.json.JSONArray;
>
> import org.json.JSONException;
>
> import org.json.JSONObject;

Go through this [website](http://json.org/java/%E2%80%8E)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[Simple HttpClient to send/receive JSON Objects](https://github.com/znq/Simple-HTTP-Client)

If it doesn't help, try sending POST request using curl to server as follows:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"m@m.com","password":"mmmmm","apikey":"12345","class":"User"}' http://YOUR_URL_PATH
```

Replace your url in the above command and run it on terminal/ command line. See if it gets the response (it could be that the script doesn't return you correct response)

Answer (score 0):

typecast  `HttpResponse resp = client.execute(post);` into `HttpResponse resp =(HttpResponse) client.execute(post);` still not able to solve just check the response by hitting url on browser wehter response json is well formed or not.